# How can I handle static files with Python webapp2 in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, static-files, webapp2

I am now migrating my small Google App Engine app to Heroku platform. I don't actually use Bigtable, and `webapp2` reduces my migration costs a lot.

Now I'm stuck on handling the static files.

Is there any good practices? If so, lead me there please.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Well, I'm now using `paste` for my WSGI server. And `paste.StaticURLParser()` should be what I need to implement static file handler. However I have no idea how to integrate it with `webapp2.WSGIApplication()`. Could anyone help me?

Maybe I need to override `webapp2.RequestHandler` class to load `paste.StaticURLParser()` properly;

```
import os
import webapp2
from paste import httpserver

class StaticFileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    u"""Static file handler"""

    def __init__(self):
        # I guess I need to override something here to load
        # `paste.StaticURLParser()` properly.
        pass

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/static', StaticFileHandler)], debug=True)


def main():
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Below is how I got this working.

I'm guessing that relying on a cascade app isn't the most efficient option, but it works well enough for my needs.

```
from paste.urlparser import StaticURLParser
from paste.cascade import Cascade
from paste import httpserver
import webapp2
import socket


class HelloWorld(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello cruel world.')

# Create the main app
web_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HelloWorld),
])

# Create an app to serve static files
# Choose a directory separate from your source (e.g., "static/") so it isn't dl'able
static_app = StaticURLParser("static/")

# Create a cascade that looks for static files first, then tries the webapp
app = Cascade([static_app, web_app])

def main():
    httpserver.serve(app, host=socket.gethostname(), port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm gonna try this later! I didn't know about `Cascade`.

Comment: You can just serve static files during development by using a variable like: if DEBUG: etc. and on production use like nginx.

Answer (score 2):

this makes your code more friendly to deploy since you can use nginx to serve your static media in production.

```
def main():
  application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, config=_config, debug=DEBUG)
  if DEBUG:
    # serve static files on development
    static_media_server = StaticURLParser(MEDIA_ROOT)
    app = Cascade([static_media_server, application])
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8000')
else:
    httpserver.serve(application, host='127.0.0.1', port='8000')
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider me late to the game, but I actually like DirectoryApp a little better.  It handles things a bit more like AppEngine.  I can create a "static" directory in my src directory, and then I can reference those in my HTML (or whatever) like this: http:..localhost:8080/static/js/jquery.js

```
static_app = DirectoryApp("static")

# Create a cascade that looks for static files first, then tries the webapp
app = Cascade([static_app,wsgi_app])

httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0',
                 port='8080')
```