# cannot access webserver resources using virtualenv and webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, webapp2

I wanted to create a simple app using webapp2.  Because I have Google App Engine installed, and I want to use it outside of GAE, I followed the instructions on this page: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html

This all went well, my main.py is running, it is handling requests correctly. However, I can't access resources directly.

`http://localhost:8080/myimage.jpg` or `http://localhost:8080/mydata.json`

always returns a 404 resource not found page.
  It doesn't matter if I put the resources on the WebServer/Documents/ or in the folder where the virtualenv is active.

Please help! :-)

(I am on a Mac 10.6 with Python 2.7)

Comment: [This](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah, cheers. I was looking into that as well, but so far it's not working. I'll edit the question.

Comment: The documentation you've linked to is for using webapp2 without GAE - are you using it or not? If not, then app.yaml isn't applicable...

Comment: yep, it's _outside_ GAE. Adding yaml file had no effect on the problem. I'll remove that part from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935103/serve-stylesheet-with-webapp2-outside-of-google-app-engine))

Looks like webapp2 doesn't have a static file handler; you'll have to roll your own. Here's a simple one:

```
import mimetypes

class StaticFileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        # edit the next line to change the static files directory
        abs_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)
        try:
            f = open(abs_path, 'r')
            self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type', mimetypes.guess_type(abs_path)[0])
            self.response.out.write(f.read())
            f.close()
        except IOError: # file doesn't exist
            self.response.set_status(404)
```

And in your `app` object, add a route for `StaticFileHandler`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), # or whatever it's called
                               (r'/static/(.+)', StaticFileHandler), # add this
                               # other routes
                              ])
```

Now `http://localhost:8080/static/mydata.json` (say) will load `mydata.json`.

Keep in mind that this code is a potential **security risk**: It allows any visitors to your website to read everything in your static directory. For this reason, you should keep all your static files to a directory that doesn't contain anything you'd like to restrict access to (e.g. the source code).

Comment: thanks for getting back to this. I think I understand now. So webapp2 is actually a webserver as well, it catches all the requests on port 8080, bypassing the standard (apache) request handling, and leaves it to the programmer to provide an implementation for handling http requests. So even the elementary GET request triggered by a <img src="myimage" /> has no default implementation in webapp2. It's up to the programmer to provide it. Did I summarize correctly?

Comment: That's about right as far as webapp2 is concerned. Don't know about Apache's default handling, so can't comment on that.