# Python - CSS Not Working in Embedded HTML

Tags: python, html, css

I am having trouble getting the CSS to link properly. It's named correctly. It just doesn't want to work. I've tried every possible way to type it out. I've heard a bunch of different things. Some say you have to type the entire project URL out (simple-login/css/style.css). I've also heard you just have to go up one level (../css/style.css). I've also heard you don't have to do that (css/style.css). Nothing seems to want to work. It always works fine in regular HTML files. Do I have to import something? I'm really getting frustrated. I'm not supposed to embed the CSS directly in this project. It's got to be a separate file.

```
import webapp2 #Use the webapp2 Library

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): #declaring a class
    def get(self):
        if self.request.GET: #variables that store the information from the forms. This information will be used in the write() method to put the information on the page. Parts of the html, stored in variables, are strung together in the write() method.
            user = self.request.GET['user']
            email = self.request.GET['email']
            games = self.request.GET['games']
            city = self.request.GET['city']
            state = self.request.GET['state']
            gender = self.request.GET['gender']
            self.response.write(Page.interface_head + Page.interface_body + Page.interface_info + Page.info_name + user + '</br>' + Page.info_email + email + '</br>' + Page.info_games + games + '</br>' + Page.info_city + city + ', ' + state + '</br>' + Page.info_gender + gender + Page.info_close + Page.interface_closing)
        else: #This is what the write method does when there is no response to the request. Meaning this is the page you are met with in the beginning. Parts of the html, stored in variables, are strung together in the write() method.
            self.response.write(Page.interface_head + Page.interface_body + Page.interface_forms + Page.interface_closing)

class Page(object):
        interface_head = '''<!Doctype HTML> <!--This houses all code in the head of my HTML including the style portion.-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Form</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>'''

        interface_body = '''<nav><h2>Game<span>Stuff</span></h2></nav> <!--This is the code for the nav all the way down to the forms.-->'''

        interface_info = '''<div class='info_background'> <!--This is the start of the div that houses the information entered from the forms. Below are all the labels split up into vriables. This is for organization and will be reassembled in the if and else statement.-->
            <h3>Is this information correct?</h3>'''
        info_name = '''<label>Name: </label>'''
        info_email = '''<label>Email: </label>'''
        info_games = '''<label>Favorite Games: </label>'''
        info_city = '''<label>City/State: </label>'''
        info_gender = '''<label>Gender: </label>'''
        info_close = '''
        </br><button>Yes</button><button>No</button></div>'''
        interface_forms = '''<form method='GET'><!--These forms enter the information to be stored in the variables in the if statement.-->
            <h3>Sign Up for a free account!</h3>
            <label>Name: </label><input type='text' name='user' />
            <label>Email: </label><input type='text' name='email' /></br>
            <label>Favorite Games: </label><input type='text' name='games' />
            <label>City: </label><input type='text' name='city' style='width: 120px;' />
            <label>State: </label><select name='state'>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <label>Gender: </label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other"> Other
        <input type="submit" value='Create Account'/> <!--This submit button finalizes all the information put in the forms.-->
        </form>'''

        interface_closing = '''
            <footer>&copy;Made by Matt Lee</footer> <!--This is a footer I made just so there was something final on the page.-->
    </body>
</html>'''

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: What is your framework?  With a WSGI app, it might not serve static files.  You might need something like nginx for that

Comment: This is just regular Python in the Google App Engine Launcher. No frameworks.

Comment: Why aren't you using templates? You shouldn't be building up HTML in Python.

Comment: Because that's what the project requires. The only thing I need is answers about the CSS.

Comment: what does your rendered html say about location of css?

Comment: The example you've provided includes a lot of unnecessary code.  Please use a minimal, complete and verifiable example to demonstrate the problem: finding the correct path to pass for your CSS file.  The html for that could be just an empty `<body></body>` with one style on it in the css.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think what you're looking for is to add a static file handler like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935103/serve-stylesheet-with-webapp2-outside-of-google-app-engine.  From the webapp2 docs, it also appears that you could configure this route via `app.yaml` instead.  http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html

Comment: tedmiston's answer worked! All I had to do was add a new handler in the app.yaml and now it works! Thank you so much! You should add an actual answer to this question so I can give you a check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use [Jinja 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/generating-dynamic-content-templates). It will help you to organize your code. It is a template language which is really good to use with Webapp2.