# How to link static css files in jinja2 using webapp2 server?

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

I am using my own webapp2 server, and jinja2 template engine for html and css. 
i have tried to link css files in my html page but i couldn't link the css static files, can any body help me please how to link css files in jinja2 using own webapp2 server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A simple example of Django and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145994/a-simple-example-of-django-and-css)

Comment: i am not using Django, i am using webapp2

Comment: Apologies. I misread your question. Perhaps this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470733/how-can-i-handle-static-files-with-python-webapp2-in-heroku

Comment: it's ok, thank you for suggested me the link but it's not working, i have found the solution, let me answer it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of my question, i have added the [webapp2_static library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webapp2_static/0.1) and it works for me